# Decorating class and its members after instantiation

Tags: python, decorator

I'm attempting to create some decorators which will allow class members to be decorated on instantiation, because I'd like to have some instances which are decorated and others which aren't.

In the example below, the intended outcome of applying the `once` decorator to an instance of `SomeClass` is that when `some_func` has been called, calling `other_func` prints a message rather than calling the original function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import functools

def some_once(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._new_attr:
            print("don't have new attr yet")
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self._new_attr = True

    return wrapped

def other_once(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._new_attr:
            print("We have a new attr")
        else:
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

def once(cls):
    setattr(cls, "_new_attr", False)
    setattr(cls, "some_func", some_once(cls.some_func))
    setattr(cls, "other_func", other_once(cls.other_func))
    return cls

class SomeClass:

    def some_func(self, parameter):
        return "The parameter is " + str(parameter)

    def other_func(self, parameter):
        return "The other parameter is " + str(parameter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = SomeClass()
    print(dir(a))
    print(a.some_func("p1"))
    print(a.other_func("p2"))

    b = once(SomeClass())
    print(dir(b))
    print(b.some_func("p3"))
    print(b.other_func("p4"))
```

The problem that results is that rather than looking at `self._new_attr`, the decorated functions instead look at `string._new_attr`, where the string is the parameter to the functions. I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't decorate an instance. Make a new, decorated class.

Changing this line:

```
b = once(SomeClass())
```

into:

```
b = once(SomeClass)()
```

Should do the trick. `once(SomeClass)` gives you a new, decorated class. In the next step make an instance of it.